# Should the login logic be removed from the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, onion-architecture

I am trying to follow best practice and ensure my controllers lean where the main business logic is performed in a service layer.

In my action below I have extracted the Validate Login code to a service layer but am unsure where the logic should go that deals with HttpConext.GetOwinContext.Authentication and creates the claim identity?

It seems there is too much code in this controller action or is it ok to keep it here?
Should it stay in the controller or be extracted into its own service infrastructure or static class of some kind?

I am a bit stuck on where this would be or what it hold.

I am trying to follow the Onion Architecture http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/

```
    public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_service.ValidateLogin(model.CustomerCode, model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                var user = _service.GetUserByUsername(model.Username);
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.Username),
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name)
                                }, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true
                }, identity);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Client Code, Username or Password");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Extracting it to it's own service ensures that you can reuse the code without having to rewrite this if say you have multiple front ends for your system. If that is not an issue then you can probably get away with leaving it in the controller.

Comment: So if I extract it into a service is it ok to pass in HttpContext into the service? Or I guess I could pass the type IAuthenticationMangaer so the service layer does not need to know about HttpContext. But the service would still need to reference Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes and System.Security.Claims.